# Error in setting go path for all user.

Tags: go

I have installed go and successfully setup it's path.
In order to run hello.py I have to run

```
   sudo go run hello.go
```

but I want to run it from

```
  go run hello.go
```

but it doesn't work. I did path setup in
      .bashrc
and
      .profile
do I have to do anything more?

Comment: what do you get with `echo $GOPATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do a manual installation, entirely in your `$HOME` (that way, `root` is never involved, and you won't have to do any `sudo`.

```
mkdir ~/golang
cd ~/golang
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.3.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar -xzf go1.3.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

Add the following lines to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export GOROOT=$HOME/golang/go 
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
export GOPATH=~/golang/yourProjects
```

Then

```
mkdir -p ~/golang/yourProjects/src
```

And you can start playing with `~/golang/yourProjects/src/hello.go`.

See more about go workspace (the folder referenced by `$GOPATH`) in "[How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces)".